# k8s: adding a sidecar to an existent POD/Deployment?

Tags: storage, kubernetes

Is it possible to add a sidecar container to an already created (active) POD/Deployment?, if so, how can I do it?

My original problem is: 
 I have a Deployment running and using a PV claimed as ReadWriteOnce. After a few days of storing data, there might happen that I need to copy the contents to another volume (can be an NFS volume).
 I'm trying to perform the copy using a sidecar (declared as Kind: Job) but it fails when trying to attach the PV (source volume)

PS: I'm simplifying the original problem description but let's assume for some reason the copy of the data can not be foreseen before setting up everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just apply your manifest including old container and the new sidecar:

```
 kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml --namespace=mynamespace
```

k8s will recreate your already existent container (this is what I was trying to avoid, any service interruption but according to kubernetes documentation this is the way it works).